# Entity hierarchy in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, orm, hierarchical-data, hibernate-mapping, object-relational-model

What's the proper way to create 2 entities where 1 is a parent of the other?  For example, we have the following 2 tables:

```
Email_Outbox
------------
Id
Email_Id
Date_Sent

Email_Outbox_Schedule
---------------------
Id
Email_Id
Date_Sent
Date_to_Send
```

Pretty simple, we have emails that go out immediately in `EmailOutbox` and emails that go out at a specified date in `EmailOutboxSchedule`.  So ideally, this is a class hierarchy in Java where `EmailOutboxSchedule` extends `EmailOutbox`.  Then we only need to specify 1 extra field, `dateToSend`, and can take advantage of typical object hierarchy features.  Is there a problem doing this with hibernate?  Do I need to annotate the 2 entities in any special way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by [this document](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1168), the solution I see is to use the @MappedSuperclass for a parent class Email_Outbox and then have two child classes Scheduled_Email_Outbox and Immediate_Email_Outbox.

Immediate_Email_Outbox would be empty except for the @Entity annotation.

An empty class is hardly elegant, I admit, but it seems like it would work. (And hibernate and elegance are somewhat incompatible anyway.)

Comment: It will work but would not represent hierarchy that is required. But it is a reasonable solution (as reasonable as just having nullable schedule column, for example).

Comment: Very funny comment about hibernate and elegance :).  This seems to make the most sense.  It's definitely better than having a nullable schedule column in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to read about [Hibernate inheritance mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html). Logically, however, I don't buy that schedule extends inbox. It sounds more that schedule is a property of individual messages. So may be just have nullable property `date to send` on a single message entity?

Comment: I could make dateToSend null for emails that need to go out immediately, but I'd much rather have separate tables and classes.  I'd disagree about whether EmailOutboxSchedule is a subclass EmailOutbox, but I'm more curious about the proper mechanism of representing object hierarchies in hibernate than this specific example.  The link to Hibernate inheritance mapping is to a JIRA issue which doesn't seem to have to do with this.. I searched and chapter 10 of the manual describes inheritance mapping, but I want something actually much simpler, 2 separate tables - 1 class hierarchy.

Comment: Apologies for wrong link, must have stuck in clipboard on my tab. Corrected. If you really want to use hierarchy and you want to use tables that you described then you can consider `Table per concrete class`.